# jQuery Routes Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-routing

JQuery Routes Plugin. http://routesjs.com/

sample url : ../support/overview
No problem

```
$.routes({        
  "/support/overview": function(){}

});
```

---

** In this way, the url does not work **

**/support/overview/?id=1&cid=1**

```
$.routes({        
  "/support/overview": function(){}

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. It seems to be "how does this plugin work?" but I can't be certain.

Comment: Hmmm I'm sorry,

 I gave the url does not match the sample with the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to be submitting this url

```
/support/overview/?id=1&cid=1
```

like so:

```
/support/overview/1/1
```

and to write your route

```
"/support/overview": function(){}
```

like so:

```
"/support/overview/:id/:cid": function(){}
```

That should fix your problems.